# json decode file names when uploading multiple images and loop through them

Tags: php, json

I am using a plugin ( I would have checked the manual if there was one for this) that already json_encodes() the file names when uploading multiple images. The only help I have so far works for one image only.

```
$response = array();
$message = "";

$files = $_POST['files']; 

    foreach (json_decode($files) as $key => $value) { 

     $image = $value->file_name; 

} 


if($_POST['files'] == "[]") { 

    $message .= "At least one image required";  

    } 

    if($message) { 

        $response['success'] = false; 
        $response['message'] = $message; 

    } else { 

        $response['success'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = $image; 
    } 

    echo json_encode($response);
```

This is the jquery/ajax

```
var uploader = $('.picker-uploader').uploader({
                upload_url: 'upload.php',
                file_picker_url: 'files.php',
                input_name: 'file',
                maximum_total_files: 5,
                maximum_file_size: 50009000,
                file_types_allowed: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'],
                on_error: function(err) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Upload Failed",
                        text: err.messages,
                        type: "warning"
                    })
                }
            })

$( "#edit_pic" ).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         var files = $('input[name="file"]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/add-support-images.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {files: files},
            beforeSend: function() {
                $( "#edit_pic" ).prop("disabled", true).html("Uploading...");
            },
        })

        .done(function(data) {
                if(!data.success) {
                console.log(data.message);

            } else {

                alert(data.message);
            }
    })
```

The upload button is in a tab:

```
<div id="addimages" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p></p>
        <label>Additional Images</label>
        <p></p>
        <button type="button" class="picker-uploader btn btn-primary">Select images</button>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <button type="submit" name="edit_pic" class="btn btn-fill btn-info" id="edit_pic">Update</button>
    <p></p>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="image_error"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="image_success"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I then want to json_encode() that again but if I choose more than one file it only outputs the last uploaded file. I need to loop through $image as well but not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: Add your form html code.

Comment: @ChristosLytras, done.

Comment: I can't see the file input field. Please add that html code too. You are passing just one input element value. You need to go through all them.

Comment: @ChristosLytras, the file input is generated via jQuery. I have added that code to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just sending only one value of the first input field now by using this code:

```
var files = $('input[name="file"]').val();
```

Try change:

```
var files = $('input[name="file"]').val();
```

to:

```
var files = $('input[name="file"]').map(function() {
    return $( this ).val();
}).get();
```

**EDIT**

The code of uploaded files recursing works fine, however, you have to decide how are you going to handle those files. You either collect all the filenames, or you do something with those files. For example, if you want to store the filenames, you can do it like this:

```
$response = array();
$message = "";
$images = array();

$files = $_POST['files']; 

foreach (json_decode($files) as $key => $value) { 
    $images[] = $value->file_name; 
}

print_r($images) // This is to see the contents of the array
```

when you just do

```
$image = $value->file_name;
```

you are overriding the `$image` variable, which contains the previous filename loaded by the `foreach` loop.

Comment: thanks for your post. I get an error when using your code: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Try to get rid of json. Remove it from ajax call, comment `dataType: 'json'`, replace `json_decode($files)` with `$files` and try again.

Comment: Hmm. Tried that and I get "undefined" in console. If I just do this: `$files = json_decode($_POST['files']);` then in console I get the data I want but the problem with this plugin is that it also carries a whole bunch of info that I don't want with it, like file size and some other details. The point of this line: ` $image = $value->file_name;` is to extract only the file name. Is it not possible to put that into a loop?

Comment: Try to turn json back on and change `foreach (json_decode($files) as $key => $value) {` with `foreach ($files as $key => $value) {` and try to `$file = json_decode($value)` then use the `$file->file_name`

Comment: I am a bit lost at the end. Do you mean this?  `$files = $_POST['files'];
 
 foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
  
  $file = json_decode($value);
  
 }`

Comment: Yes exactly. That means that now you enumerate thw array of files and you decode each file separately. Sorry, I'm on my smartphone and can't test/type as I want.

Comment: Where does `$file->file_name` go?

Comment: Inside `foreach` loop after `$file = json_decode($value);`

Comment: I get this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @user8463989 I think there is something missing from your code you have pasted. Can you tell me which plugin do you use and where did you get that code from? Maybe there is an example online I can check?

Comment: Cool. When I console.log the data I get file names separated by commas. When I try use  $images as a variable in my SQL insert statement, the database records all show "Array", instead of the actual image name?

Comment: Well, the variable `$images` is now an array that has elements and each element hold a filename. You have to deside how do you want to store that array in MySQL. You can store it as it is in a field of type TEXT or VARCHAR. You can use PHP functions `serialize()` to save to database and `unserialize()` to convert it back to array when retrieving the data from the database; or you can even use `json_encode` to store and `json_decode` to retrieve. Here is an example that uses `serialize`/`unserialize` with the database http://kimjoyfox.com/serialize-php-array-for-mysql-database/

Comment: Thank you. I serialized in in php but got a weird result in the database. a:2:{i:0;N;i:1;N;}

Comment: Are you sure you did a `serialize($images)`? That array you did serialize, is just an array containing 2 `NULL` values!

Comment: @user8463989 if you got that shorted out, then please accept my answer. To see how you can accept an answer, read here [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).